# Create multiple TestServers with WebHostBuilder in .NET 6 for integration test with multple projects (Program.cs)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

Is it possible to create multiple TestServers for an integration test in dotnet 6?

With dotnet 3.1 this was possible because I could reference Startup.cs from the integration test. With dotnet 6 the Program.cs and Startup.cs became Program.cs. Now when I try to reference the Program.cs for the WebHostBuilder.UseStartup() this is not possible because I have multiple Program.cs and the Program.cs files don't have a namespace.

In dotnet 3.1 I had

```
var application1 = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Poject1.Startup>()
var application2 = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Poject2.Startup>()
var application3 = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Poject3.Startup>()
```

In dotnet 6 this is not possible?

```
var application1 = new WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>().UseStartup<Poject1.Program>()
var application2 = new WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>().UseStartup<Poject2.Program>()
var application3 = new WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>().UseStartup<Poject3.Program>()
```

I get the error: The Type 'Program' exists in both 'Project1...' and 'Project2...'

The Program.cs files look like this:

```
// usings

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// inject services

var app = builder.Build();

// configure services

app.Run();

public partial class Program { }
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Post the actual code and actual *full* exception text or compilation error. The error tells you that the `Program` classes are mixed up. Somehow, somewhere it's unclear which `Program` class is used.

Comment: The problem is obvious but there is not solution for it when I search the Microsoft documentation or stackoverflow. I have 3 projects with 3 Program.cs. In .NET 3.1 the Startup.cs classes had namespaces but the new Program.cs classes don't have a namespace so I can't use 'Project1.Program' for example

Comment: The problem may be obvious to you but I can't tell if that's a compilation error or exception, or where it's raised. [Integration testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is typically performed through the `WebApplcationFactory<>` class, not by starting a real host

Comment: Googling for `The Type 'Program' exists in both` shows this is a compilation error with hits going back to 2006. It's caused when the same type *in the same namespace* appears in multiple assemblies or assembly versions. This error was also reported in ASP.NET MVC 2 projects from 2011, because the code generation used by ASP.NET resulted in classes being created in the same (perhaps the global?) namespace. This may be the case here too.

Comment: In any case, if you want to start several services for integration testing starting multiple hosts is a *dangerous* idea. All hosts run under the same process so they aren't isolated. Static data will be common for all hosts. If you have a common library with some singletons or static classes, making a modification in one project will be visible to all others as well. In such cases it's better to containerize the projects and start them in separate containers just for testing

Comment: It may not even be your code. A lot of libraries use caching in static fields. Serializers cache type information and metadata for example. One example is XmlSerializer.

Comment: I get what you are saying. I can use WebApplcationFactory<Program> but the problem here is that I cannot reference 3 different Program.cs files because they do not have a namespace. The namespace is removed because with dotnet 6 you can write it like the example I have written in the description. So I need a namespace in my Program.cs files. But I think the only solution then is to make a Program.cs and Startup.cs file the old dotnet 3.1 way

Comment: When you use `Project1.Program` you *are* specifying a namespace, `Project1`. That's why this is weird and why you need to post the actual code *and actual full compilation error*. Where does the error appear?

Comment: Project1 is the project name. I want to use 3 different Program.cs files from 3 different projects in my integration test but the Program.cs files don't have a namespace in the new .net 6.

Comment: That's not what I asked. It's clear from the start that you want to use 3 projects. What isn't clear is the actual test code, the actual full error text and its location. Besides, top-level programs don't use `new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Poject1.Program>()`, they use `WebApplication.CreateBuilder`. I don't know if `UseStartup` can guess that you have a top-level file that needs to be executed instead of a `Startup` with well known method names. I'd guess not. That's why you'd need `WebApplicationFactory<Project1.Program>`

Comment: `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` creates a plain old builder. It doesn't involve any extra customization or configuration nor does it care about `Startup` or `Program`. You could run your customization code on it, just like you do in `Program.cs`. Which means that if you extract your configuration code to a separate static method, you'll be able to apply it to that builder too. You won't need to create the `Program` class. That's only there for *WebApplicationFactory*.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time so far. But when I use WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>().UseStartup<TProgram>() I need to reference the 3 Program.cs files aswell. But that is not possible or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you please provide an example of how one can create 3 different Programs and map each one to a different WebApplicationFactory? Or rather, how can I use the same program but have 3 different WebApplicationFactory classes with different configurations?  I can't seem to be able to access the WebApplication instance from inside WebApplicationFactory.

Comment: @Brian did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may change your `Program` classes adding different namespace to each one:

```
namespace Project1; // <- Note the namespaces here

public partial class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        //Add services , etc - the whole content of Program.cs
    }
}
```

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73446944/1440095), there will be no side effects.

---