# Will adding a namespace and a Main method to Program.cs in ASP.NET Core 6 have any negative effects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, toplevel-statement

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web Api application.

Currently, the `Program.cs` uses the new program style with top-level statements as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates). This means that it does not have a namespace.

There is a [bug](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/c-10-why-sq-requires-us-to-move-public-partial-class-program-to-a-named-namespace/69573) in SonarQube 9.3 which raises an error on this point. This bug has been fixed with version 9.6, but it will take time until we update the version at our side.

Therefore, I need a temporary solution so avoid SonarQube errors.

I am thinking of converting `Program.cs` to the old coding style.

```
namespace Aa;

public partial class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        //Add services , etc - the whole content of Program.cs
    }
}
```

I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) that in a console application they are equivalent.

My question is: what about Web API? Can I safely add a `namespace` and a `Main` method in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API? Will there be any side effects?

Comment: `Can I safely add a namespace and a Main method` Yes.  `Will there be any side effects` No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minimize side-effects, just copy your top-level statements into a Main method  declared in a namespace scope like this:

```
namespace foo
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Main()
        {
            //top level statements here
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then any other types declared in your Program.cs will remain in the global namespace.  In any case possible consequences are limited to compilation errors from moving types to a different namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can safely add a Program.Main.

Comment: Here's the [Program.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/spa-templates/blob/main/src/content/Angular-CSharp/Program.Main.cs) that's generated (`#if` is processed out) when creating a new project without top-level statements